# Using Transaction in ADO.net SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am new to ADO, so I want to ask if I did right using transaction.
Here the code snippet

```
string SQL1 = "INSERT INTO tbl_cust(cust_id,cust_name) values ('000001','YoungMcD') ";
string SQL2 = "UPDATE tbl_cust SET custname='OldMcDonald' WHERE cust_id='000001'";
string SQL3 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_supplier WHERE supplier_code ='000001'";

// write connstring
string conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString;
// end of connection string

// setting connection
SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(conn);
SqlTransaction transaction1;

db.Open();
transaction1 = db.BeginTransaction();

try
{
    // insert to table
    SqlCommand Com1 = new SqlCommand(SQL1, db, transaction1);
    Com1.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlCommand Com2 = new SqlCommand(SQL2, db, transaction1);
    Com2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlCommand Com3 = new SqlCommand(SQL3, db, transaction1);
    Com3.ExecuteNonQuery();

    transaction1.Commit();

    db.Close();
}
catch
{
    transaction1.Rollback();
    db.Close();
    msg = "error";
    goto endret;
}
```

For transaction, should I use

```
SqlCommand Com1 = new SqlCommand(SQL1, db, transaction1);
```

instead of

```
SqlCommand Com1 = new SqlCommand(SQL1, db);
```

because I already state begin transaction before `try{}` statement

EDIT:

I get it, First syntax is applicable, but how to use ADO effectively?. I find that this way is too straightforward.

I found myself keep doing this for inserting parameter, ex:

```
string SQL1 = "INSERT INTO tbl_cust(cust_id,cust_name) values ('" + param1 +"','"+ param2 +"') ";
```

Comment: You need to use the first to tell sql which transaction the command belongs to  as you could have multiple transaction going at the same time.

Comment: Please note that while this will work, you are actually making 5 round trips between your application and the sql server. The same actions can be completed with just one round trip using a stored procedure.

Comment: Can I ask for explanation of what do you mean about making 5 round trips? because I don't get it, and why doing this is more inferior than  creating Stored Procedure

Comment: So, an exception from `db.Close()` will cause the code to try to rollback a transaction? This is clearly wrong. Move `db.Close()` outside the `try..catch` block.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A lot has been happened since last year.Here I tried to simplified the answer.

```
string ConnStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString;
string SQL1 = "INSERT INTO tbl_cust(cust_id,cust_name) values ('000001','YoungMcD') ";
string SQL2 = "UPDATE tbl_cust SET custname='OldMcDonald' WHERE cust_id='000001'";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
{
    SqlTransaction transaction = null;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL1, conn, transaction)) { cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); }
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL2, conn, transaction)) { cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); }
        transaction.Commit();
        savestats = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
        try
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred
            // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as
            // a closed connection.
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why transaction is declared outside of `try{}` so we can rollback it in `catch{}`.

The downfall of this code is when error happened in `conn.Open()` for whatever the reason is, then attempt of `transaction.Rollback()` will cause exception.

That's why another `try{}` `catch{}` added to handle it.

Comment: You can always use a Try Catch overall to manage connection error and in Ado.Net calls I usually intercept all exceptions and return an object with both the result data and the error message and all pertaining so that the calling class manages the errors and we avoid the unhandled exceptions from low level classes as Data Provider classes.

Answer (score 5):

You should use one Command and also wrap your connection in a Using block so its properly disposed. Additionally, you should read from tbl_supplier after the transaction has been committed by executing a [SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx). I'm assuming you just wanted to know how many rows were affected after the transaction committed.

Here is a simplified version of your code.

```
var conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString;
string SQL1 = "INSERT INTO tbl_cust(cust_id,cust_name) values ('000001','YoungMcD') ";
string SQL2 = "UPDATE tbl_cust SET custname='OldMcDonald' WHERE cust_id='000001'";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlTransaction sqlTran = connection.BeginTransaction();
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.Transaction = sqlTran;

    try
    {
        command.CommandText = SQL1;
        int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.CommandText = SQL2;
        rowsAffected += command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex1)
    {
        // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
        try
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred
            // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as
            // a closed connection.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Delete the rollback as well.

Comment: The transaction really should be in a `using` block. Also, with the order of your code, I don't think the command will be enlisted in the transaction.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I agree putting the transaction in a using block would be more elegant. Not sure about your second point. What's wrong with the order? Not following.

Comment: Take a look at the following MSDN. Feel fre to edit my answer. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k2hy99x(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The main problem was your old code was missing the `command.Transaction = sqlTran`, adding that fixed the problem.